# PHP generated Js function calls are created with line breaks

Tags: javascript, php

I'm using PHP to call a Js function with values generated by PHP.

```
$fp = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'rb');

while(($line = fgets($fp)) !== false)
{
    $split = explode(":", $line);

    echo '
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var a = updateHashes("' . $split[0] . '", "' . $split[1] . '"); 
        console.log(a); 
    </script>'; 
}
```

But my code adds some line breaks to the code, which cause errors as you can see in the following screenshot:

[image]

What could I do to fix this?

Comment: `line` ends in a newline doesn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add [trim()](http://php.net/trim)

```
echo '
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var a = updateHashes("' . trim($split[0]) . '", "' . trim($split[1]) . '"); 
        console.log(a); 
    </script>';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the php trim() function on each line, that should solve.

```
$split = explode(":", trim($line));
```